Concrete Fence Base Exposed
I dug a 2’ deep garden bed right under my fence posts, exposing the concrete bases. The dirt was clay and fairly substantial. I intend to backfill in a week with a mix of soil that will be lighter. Thoughts on need to secure the posta with some kind of retaining wall/s prior to backfilling?  Thanks in advance!


Photo not showing/linking.  The ground is the main sideways support for any fence posts.  Cray ground is usually tougher than other types, but will depend on fence height/type and wind force on the fence.  Back filling plus packing before the next big wind will help.

Thanks.  There’s not crazy wind being in a city, and fairly surrounded by buildings. unless there’s a violent storm. my main concern was soil underneath each post eroding possibly because the garden bed might have worms or other things aerating it. Here’s the photo: https://share.icloud.com/photos/0e7nhGwwztXTSAufOt-Gu25bw

How deep do the posts go? A few inches exposed may be harmless. My cedar fence posts go down to the frost line, 4 feet  below the surface; moving the surface a bit would have little to no effect.
